# how can i bind the shapes i have defined in code behind in a datagrid column?

Tags: c#, xaml, wpfdatagrid

So here is my problem. I have build this simple interface in xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="302" Width="253.8">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtbxName}">_Cerca una lista</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="Inserisci il nome di una lista per filtrare l'elenco"/>
            <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="dg"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyFilteredItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,1.2,0" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header >
                            <CheckBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Checked="IsChecked" Unchecked="IsUncheck" ToolTip="Seleziona/Deseleziona tutto"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="c1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="{Binding Check}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>Name</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Dimension}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>Dimensione</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Colour}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>Colour</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,35.4" Grid.Row="1" Width="60">Applica</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,35.4" Grid.Row="1" Width="60">Nascondi</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,35.4" Grid.Row="1" Width="60">Cancella</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My grid take data from an observable collection of a class made like this:

```
public class Righe :  INotifyPropertyChanged 
        {
            private bool check;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public bool Check
            {
                get { return check; }
                set
                {
                    check = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged("Check");
                }
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Dimension { get; set; }
            public Rectangle rect;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
```

I want, instead of `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Colour}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>Colour</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>`

a column that have in each cell the rectangle shape that i have defined in my class. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this approach is bad because it doesn't fit the MVVM, but if you know what you do you can use DataGridTemplateColumn

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding rect}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```